# Freeing memory failure: free(): invalid next size (fast):

Tags: c++, debugging, memory, free, allocation

I have a matrix class which dynamically reallocates size. To be specific: dynamically reallocates an array of rows.

But in some cases there is a memory freeing problem when matrix's destructor is called:

> *** glibc detected *** ./solver: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000000c112b0 ***

and the process is being aborted.

The Matrix class:

```
#ifndef __matrix_hpp
#define __matrix_hpp

#include <cstring>
#include <stdexcept>
#include "row.hpp"

using namespace std;

class Matrix {

public:
    Matrix();
    ~Matrix();
    size_t size();
    void resize(size_t size);
    double get(size_t x, size_t y) throw (out_of_range);
    void set(size_t x, size_t y, double value) throw (out_of_range);
    double getfv(size_t y) throw (out_of_range);
    void setfv(size_t y, double value) throw (out_of_range);
    void optimize(size_t y) throw (out_of_range);
    void _print();

private:
    size_t sz;
    Row **data;

};

#endif
```

And the body of significant functions:

```
Matrix::~Matrix() {
    if (data != NULL) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
            delete data[i];
        delete [] data;
    }
}

void Matrix::resize(size_t size) {
    if (size == sz)
        return;
    Row **newData = new Row *[size];
    if (data != NULL)
        memcpy(newData, data, sz * sizeof(Row*));
    if (size > sz) {
        for (size_t i = sz; i < size; ++i)
            newData[i] = new Row();
    }
    else {
        for (size_t i = size; i < sz; ++i)
            delete data[i];
    }
    delete [] data;
    data = newData;
    sz = size;
}
```

So, that's the code. The problem comes when I make a matrix and later reduce it's size and call desctructor. For example:

```
Matrix *matrix = new Matrix();
matrix->resize(10);
matrix->resize(7);
delete matrix;
```

But making matrix bigger works pretty good:

```
Matrix *matrix = new Matrix();
matrix->resize(10);
matrix->resize(13);
delete matrix;
```

And the funniest thing, this example works:

```
Matrix *matrix = new Matrix();
matrix->resize(3);
matrix->resize(2);
delete matrix;
```

So I have no idea what can be wrong. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that you write outside of your allocated space:
The culprit is this line

```
Row **newData = new Row *[size];
if (data != NULL)
    memcpy(newData, data, sz * sizeof(Row*));
```

If sz is bigger than size, then you will write too much and potentially destroyed your heap. Change it to the code below and everything should work better. This way you will always copy valid data and no more than you have allocated.

```
Row **newData = new Row *[size];
if (data != NULL)
    memcpy(newData, data, (size>sz?sz:size) * sizeof(Row*));
```

That resizing from 3 to 2 works is down to luck (and how the heap works).

Also, you don't check if new Row[] fails but that would lead to a NULL pointer exception.

Comment: That works! Thank you very much. I didn't noticed that.

But why there is a problem with freeing? I see no connection.

And do you recommend to check if new fails always? :D

Comment: The heap will store some information around the memory you got when you allocated it and if you write outside of the area you've been given you overwrite the information the heap will need to free the buffer. For the other issue, just check if it newData[i] == NULL and return an error if it is (and free any allocated memory).

Answer (score 1):

After a very cursory examination, I would bet you the problem is this:

```
if (data != NULL)
    memcpy(newData, data, sz * sizeof(Row*));
```

If you're shrinking from, say 10, to 7, you just copied 10 pointers over a buffer that's sized for 7.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you allocate some memory and write past the end of that memory, overwriting memory you do not own that is used to manage the free heap.

Review every place you write to allocated memory. Ensure you don't write past the end of the memory that you requested and rightfully own.